# Convert Raw SQL to Django ORM code , possibility

Tags: django, django-orm

Is it possible to perform something like this with only Django ORM?

```
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                """SELECT word FROM ts_stat(
                'SELECT to_tsvector(''simple'', description) FROM api_product');""",
                #[source, ]
            )
            words_in_product_model = frozenset(
                more_itertools.one(word) for word in cursor.fetchall()
```

db-Postgres 11
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) class does use the `to_tsvector` but I don't think the `ts_stat` is available.

When initially looking at your question I completely missed the fact that `ts_stat` takes a string instead of just a regular result. That changes the implementation significantly and I'm not sure what's the  best way of implementing this... but I'll give you a simple hack to work around it using the `raw` method on a queryset.

```py
from django.db import models


class TsStat(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ndoc = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    nentry = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed: False



vector_query = models.ApiProduct.objects.annotate(
    search=Func(Value('simple'), 'description', function='to_tsvector'),
).values('search')

results = TsStat.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM ts_stat(%s)' % vector_query.query)
```

But this is obviously untested, the syntax might be slightly different and you'll might have to include the `SearchVector` immediately instead of through filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesnt work this way as it says: A function with the given name and argument types was not found. Perhaps you should add explicit type conversions. I have tried TS_STAT as well

Comment: You could try to add a `Cast(...)` around it, but in this case I would probably go for a custom function instead. I'll add an example :)